# How to merge one or more nested array values having same keys

Tags: php, arrays

I'm little bit confuse in this concept

Actually I'm having an array like this

```
    $arr = array("0"=>array("username"=>"username1"),"1"=>array("username"=>"username2"),"2"=>array("username"=>"username3"),"3"=>array("username"=>"username4"));
    echo "<pre>";print_r($arr);
    $finalArray = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $arr);
    echo "<pre>";print_r($finalArray);
```

Finally from this I'm getting an array like this

```
Array
(
    [username] => username4
)
```

But I need all the values like as follows

```
Array
(
    [0] => username1
    [1] => username2
    [2] => username3
    [3] => username4
)
```

How should I do this?..Could someone please help me..

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution using `array_column` function(available since PHP 5.5):

```
$result = array_column($arr, 'username');
```

Comment: So simple.. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own function to get `usernames`

Try this

```
<?php
function getUserNames($arr){
    $userNames = array();
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value){
        $userNames[$key] = $value["username"];
    }   
    return $userNames;
}
$arr = array("0"=>array("username"=>"username1"),"1"=>array("username"=>"username2"),"2"=>array("username"=>"username3"),"3"=>array("username"=>"username4"));
echo "<pre>";print_r($arr);
$finalArray = getUserNames($arr);
echo "<pre>";print_r($finalArray);
?>
```